# Displaying Image and Message in Viewcontroller and Dissmiss after Specific Time in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, viewcontroller

I want to Display ViewController , which contains an Image and Message . This ViewController needs to be displayed when PushNotification arrives , PushNotification contains Message and some id . By id i'll fetch the Image from the server and I need to display together in Viewcontroller for specific Time Interval and Dismiss it automatically .

Till Now I have completed with PushNotification and getting the image from the server, Now Next thing I need to display it in ViewController.

Can any one please help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this,

In **appDelegate.m**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
     ViewController *vc=[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

vc.image=// set your image
vc.message=//message

     [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

in **ViewController.m**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60
    target:self
    selector:@selector(closeVc)
    userInfo:nil
    repeats:NO];
}
-(void)closeVc
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply ... I have used this logic but I can see the Empty view Controller displayed. Image and Message is not getting displayed in view controller . How to pass the values from Appdelegate to vc ?

Comment: are you set the message,images properly? that is `message` as a label you have to declare and set property, @synthesis of  it. 
**OR**
You can set it in viewcontroller's viewDidLoad Method...
in my application i have same scenario and i'm loading it in viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Yes I did in ViewDidLoad now , using appDelegate.

Comment: I need one more help , I want the view controller height to be 350 how can i do ? I have set size in storyboard but its not happening , Its getting streched

Comment: yes if you doing in this way not looks better, rather you can use [RNBlurModalView](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNBlurModalView) it will give nice look to app.

Comment: I saw the RNBlurModelView example . but Can i show the Image in that Model , I didnt find any documentation about how to display Image. Could you please help me some more

Comment: its easy you can set view (uiview with uiimage n label) and use this view to display RNBlurModel.

Comment: DisplayMessageViewController *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DisplayMessage"];;
     RNBlurModalView *modal = [[RNBlurModalView alloc] initWithViewController:self view:vc.view]; in AppDelegate but it giving Exception unrecognized selector sent to instance . is this that right way ? or i should use the model object in ViewdidLoad of  
    DisplayMessageViewController class?

Comment: and its giving the warning while initializing model :incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'AppDelegate *const __strong' to parameter of type UIViewController

Comment: you can display model object in ViewdidLoad of DisplayMessageViewController class.